# Highcharts negative color for zone in area?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there anyway to set the color for the negative portion of a zone?

My intention is to achieve something like this. Don't pay attention to the plotBands on the background.

[image]

```
You can use this as boilerplate.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/du2hobrt/

Comment: Is this an acceptable solution: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/awL81f6k/4/?

Comment: Not really, you just changed the zone axis. I need to define my zones on the xAxis.

Comment: There is no built in method for coloring the negative portion of a zone. Your best bet would be to find what is positive, and negative and color accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce series `fillOpacity` value and use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` to add layers under the series, which will affect the color:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var series = this.series[0].area,
                plotLeft = this.plotLeft;

            this.renderer.path().attr({
                translateX: plotLeft,
                translateY: this.plotTop,
                d: series.d,
                fill: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)',
                zIndex: 0
            }).add();

            this.renderer.rect(
                plotLeft,
                this.yAxis[0].toPixels(0),
                this.plotSizeX,
                this.plotTop + this.plotSizeY - this.yAxis[0].toPixels(0)

            ).attr({
                fill: '#FFF',
                zIndex: 0
            }).add()
        }
    }
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bsk3n0qz/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.fillOpacity

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a solution either. Colors for positive and negative are too afar to achieve anything similar to the image. Btw, the image comes from an existing app on my Co. Would seeing the chart can help you to know how it is being done there?

Comment: Hi Merak Marey, The effect you want to achieve is not supported by default and requires some custom and experimental solution. Currently no other solution comes to my mind. I can see the chart but I do not know if it will help.